# Unhandled rejection Error: Non-whitespace adding json to react-codemirror

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codemirror

am trying to set the value of codemirror code editor with a json that am reading using nodejs, but i keep getting an error , and if i copy the json to a notpad and then copy it again from the notepad and paste it again to the codemirror code editor it works , i cleared the whitespace and newlines but still the same , this is how i cleaned it :

```
json = json.replace(/\\/g,"").replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/\ufeff/g, "").replace(/\n/g,'');
```

this is the json, its just the package.json file:

```
{"name":"project","version":"1.0.0","description":"","main":"index.js","scripts":{"test":"echo"Error:notestspecified"&&exit1","dev":"nodemonindex.js"},"repository":{"type":"git","url":"git+https://alnator@bitbucket.org/alnator/project.git"},"author":"hasanalnatour","license":"ISC","homepage":"https://bitbucket.org/alnator/emma_node#readme","dependencies":{"apollo-client":"^1.0.4","axios":"^0.16.1","body-parser":"^1.17.1","config":"^1.25.1","content-type":"^1.0.2","cors":"^2.8.3","csv-parse":"^1.2.0","express":"^4.15.2","express-graphql":"^0.6.4","glob":"^7.1.1","glob-promise":"^3.1.0","graphql":"^0.9.3","mime-types":"^2.1.15","nodemon":"^1.11.0","pg":"^6.1.5","pg-hstore":"^2.3.2","react-apollo":"^1.0.1","sequelize":"^3.30.4","sqlite3":"^3.1.8"}}
```

i keep getting this error :

```
debuggability.js:874 Unhandled rejection Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
    Line: 0
    Column: 1
    Char: {
        at error (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:81327:11)
        at strictFail (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:81353:8)
        at beginWhiteSpace (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:81627:8)
        at SAXParser.write (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:81682:12)
        at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:80616:32)
        at Parser.parseString (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:80115:60)
        at exports.parseString (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:80648:20)
        at http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:73922:36
        at Promise._execute (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:76600:10)
        at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:74446:19)
        at new Promise (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:74042:11)
        at Converter.convertData (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:73919:15)
        at IntegrationDetails.onCodeEditorChange (http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:60549:42)
        at http://localhost:50641/static/js/bundle.js:73612:23
        at <anonymous>
```